# Aggregates in Visual Studio Reports not showing

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create a report that UNIONs two datasets. It takes (1) a bunch of orders for a specific customer within a date range, and UNIONs it with (headers and) (2) the method of shipping following by the average of the time interval between the order being placed and the order being sent.

The screenshot below shows that, in SQL Server, the query works perfectly. However, when I run this exact same query in Visual Studio 2008 to create a report for this, the actual value of the average turnaround time[image] is empty.

As far as I can tell, in SQL Server the query works perfectly for whatever parameters I give it. I just can't figure out why in the report the average turnaround time is always blank.

The query I'm running is:

```
DECLARE @turnaroundInfo TABLE
(
    [Owner Reference] VARCHAR(48),
    [Project] VARCHAR(48),
    [Carrier Type] VARCHAR(48),
    [Created Date] DATETIME,
    [Shipped Date] DATETIME,
    [Turnaround Time (hours)] INT
)
INSERT INTO @turnaroundInfo
SELECT orders.ownerReference AS [Owner Reference], p.name AS [Project], types.name AS [Carrier Type], orders.createdSysDateTime AS [Created Date], shipments.shippedDate AS [Shipped Date],  DATEDIFF(HOUR,             orders.createdSysDateTime, shipments.shippedDate) AS [Turnaround Time (hours)]
FROM datex_footprint.Orders orders
    INNER JOIN datex_footprint.Projects p ON orders.projectId = p.id
    INNER JOIN datex_footprint.CarrierServiceTypes types ON orders.preferredCarrierServiceTypeId = types.id
    INNER JOIN datex_footprint.OrderLines lines ON orders.id = lines.orderId
    INNER JOIN datex_footprint.Shipments shipments ON lines.shipmentId = shipments.id
WHERE p.name IN (@project)  AND types.name IN(@carrier)

-- Get only the type and date-ranged turnaround info we want
DECLARE @orders TABLE
(
    [Owner Reference] VARCHAR(48),
    [Project] VARCHAR(48),
    [Carrier Type] VARCHAR(48),
    [Created Date] DATETIME,
    [Shipped Date] DATETIME,
    [Turnaround Time (hours)] INT
)
INSERT INTO @orders
SELECT  *
FROM @turnaroundInfo
WHERE [Turnaround Time (hours)] >= 0 AND [Created Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
ORDER BY [Turnaround Time (hours)], [Carrier Type] ;


-- UNION the relevant turnaround infor with headers
SELECT * FROM @orders o /*  All the orders in the date range for this project and the selected carrier(s) */
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carrier' AS [Carrier Type], 'Avg Turnaround Time' AS [Average Turnaround], NULL AS Column3, NULL AS Column4, NULL AS Colummn5, NULL AS Column6
UNION ALL
SELECT o.[Carrier Type], CAST(AVG(o.[Turnaround Time (hours)]) AS NVARCHAR(24)) AS [Average Turnaround], NULL AS Column3, NULL AS Column4, NULL AS Colummn5, NULL AS Column6
FROM @orders o
GROUP BY o.[Carrier Type];
```

Does anybody know or see what I might be missing?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note: I'm not sure why the screenshot broke up that sentence, but it doesn't seem to want to let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not blank, it's just might not in the column you expected - I can see the value '24' in your screenshot.

Comment: That screenshot is from SQL Server. I was trying to show I get exactly what I expect in SQL Server, but when I run the report that 24 value is blank -- even though the query and the parameters are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my mistake was.
The column about the value 24 and the header and 24 value column were sized differently. In SQL Server, it didn't seem to care, but in Visual Studio it saw the size difference and actually dropped the whole column from displaying.

After I adjusted the average value column to VARCHAR(48), which is what the column above it was sized to, it displayed properly again.